# Do you have the way put the ajax value into php string in this situation?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to know if you have any way to put the ajax result into a php string. In the ajax sucesss: do you have other way to return the result other than `.html()`, `.text()`,`.val()`, so I can put the result into a php string directly instead of html.

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'member_search.php',
   type:'POST',
   data:{   
       search_text: $(".result_tag").text()     
    },
   error: function(){
       $('#find_members').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
   },
   success: function(data){
     $("#get_user").text(data);
    }
});
```

```html
<?php
$user=//the result of ajax return.

?>
```

Comment: PHP is running serverside and jQuery runs clientside. By the time your AJAX is running the PHP essentially doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: do you any suggestion that I can achieve what I want?

Comment: Not really - I don't mean to say this in a rude way, but asking this question indicates that you don't completely understand what you're doing. Your server side code (where your PHP is at) is going to execute separately from your client side code (where your jQuery AJAX is at) - at very least you'll need to give more information on what you're trying to accomplish before anyone's going to be able to help you, and I suggest trying to understand better what PHP and JavaScript are each for.

Comment: Actually, I want to call the bp_core_fetch_avatar(), but if I put bp_core_fetch_avatar in the url file that ajax call, it doesn't work, bp_core_fetch_avatar is a custom function from buddypress, I guess it is the same reason it doesn't work is y the time my AJAX is running the PHP essentially doesn't exist anymore,  So I think a way, put the value into html hidden input and then call it with javascript, but the problem is I could not put the var inside a php function. right now, a way to put the ajax result into a php string, and then put that string inside the bp_core_fetch_avatar().

Comment: The only way I think its possible is to take the successful ajax result and make the script load the PHP file while passing in the ajax output as a parameter and then in the php script, setting the value equal to `$_GET['parameter-name']` but your idea at best will require a minimum of three requests to the server per user. one request for the code containing the jquery, one request for member_search.php and one for the php file that stores the string as a variable. This is on top of all the other resources you're requesting just for the one page.

Comment: how to set value equal to $_GET['parameter-name']?

Comment: @kenny Please accept an answer if your initial problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request is client-side and your PHP is server-side, so it's not possible.

All the work should be done when the ajax request is received by `member_search.php`. You can't do it after by sending the result again to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing issues because you are getting confusion to send data from AJAX and receive from server as well. See below example and make changes according to your need.

```
<form class="search" action='results.php'>
<input type='text' name='keyword' >
</form>
```

Your AJAX request will look like.

```
$(".search").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('href'),
                data: $(".search").serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res.status) {
                        //Your success results or keywords
                       $("#get_user").text(res.output);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
```

And in your result.php file you should use select query according to user entered keyword or I can say put logical code here

```
    <?php if($_POST){
    //You will receive form post data and put your conditional logics

    //at last please make sure to encode your data first to transfer to AJAX. Like
    $res = array();
    $res['status'] = true;
    $res['output'] = YOUR DESIRED OUTPUT;
    echo json_encode($res); exit; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language. this means it is executed on the server itself before it renders the html. all variables in php are assigned values and consumed on the server side itself. Now this happens BEFORE anything is sent to your local machine. when you see the DOM, all the variables have done their job, and the DOM is nothing but the resultant render.

AJAX requests are sent form your local machines (clients) to the servers, they ask for data from the server or put in some data on the server. NOW, if you have the code in the post that you are making, it will work on the server side. this is how you consume the whole thing:

Client Side code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/php/file/or/function',
        type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
        dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
        data: {param: 'value'}, //these are the values you send
    })
    .done(function(receivedData) {
        alert(receivedData);
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
```

And this is your server side code:

```
<?
  function iReceivedTheData(){
    if($_POST){
        $serverSideVar = param; //this is the item you sent from the ajax request
        $response = someThingElse($serverSideVar); //this is where you do what you need to with the data you received and log that into a variable called response

        echo $response; //this is where you give the response back to the client side. this response will be the 'data' that you receive on success of the ajax request, i have alerted the same above.
    }
  }
 ?>
```

thats how you use client side values on the server side

Comment: Sorry, I confuse. Are you saying that it is impossible to do what I want. Or if I follow your example, I may get ajax result into a php string.

Comment: yes, this is an example to consume the ajax data on your server side php code

Comment: When you said if($_POST) in your example, do I have to put $_POST['NAME'] from a submit form,  or it wlll check if ajax post run or not? I had tried only if($_POST){}, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: if using chrome, inspect element, go to console. right click in console. tick log XMLHttpRequests and then submit your ajax. you will see a blue link shows up in the console. click on it, you will be taken to the network tab on chrome's inspector. that is the response from your php. check that to get more info

Comment: Thanks. I can see a lot of info. But what can I use those data to get the response value into a php string?